# How to specify a foreign key in the entity JPA

Tags: jpa, foreign-keys

I have two tables.

One table is **USER**

ID  (Primary key)
...
..

- few other fields.

Another table is **user_settings**
ID  (Primary key)

- **Userid (foreign key with user table)**
- **uuid**
- **enabled.**
  How to specify foreign key relation with user table in the entity.

Answer (score 0):

JPA allows you to define table relationships using annotations like these:
`@ManyToOne` `@OneToMany` `@OneToOne` `@ManyToMany`.

Please check out this tutorial [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jpa/jpa_entity_relationships.htm) on how JPA Entity Relationships works and how to implement them.